# What is this plane, based on its inside shape?

Tags: aircraft-identification, lufthansa

I'm not sure my question is valid here but would be very helpful to me.

Here is the picture of the inside of a plane (don't mind the ostrich). Does anyone know which plane it is? The flight number was 4357 going from Marseille to Frankfurt in 2006. I think the plane was from Lufthansa but not 100% sure. Can't find any public database for consulting historic flights.

[image]

Comment: The 2+2 seat configuration would encompasse Embraer and Bombardier.

Comment: On this website => http://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/DLH4357, it says it was a 737-500 in 2010, is it possible it was a plane like that back then ?

Comment: B737-500 is [wider](http://aeroclassifieds.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Screenshot-2016-09-09-22.43.48.png) 3+3. Could also be an ATR-72 (just trying to match the 2+2 seat configuration)

Comment: [This 2006 Lufthansa timetable](https://www.lufthansa.com/mediapool/pdf/41/media_388541.pdf) lists '143' as scheduled on the Lufthansa 4357 flight from Marseille to Frankfurt. But 143 would be Avro RJ85 which has a 3+3 configuration. If this is indeed a Lufthansa (Cityline) plane in 2006, it would be a Bombardier CRJ-100, -200 or -700 (or maybe the -900, they got delivered from June 2006). The Embraers were not in service yet with Lufthansa in 2006.

Comment: As addition to that, [the JetPhotos database](https://www.jetphotos.com/showphotos.php?aircraft=all&airline=all&country-location=location%253BMarseille%2520Marignane-Provence%2520-%2520LFML&photographer-group=all&category=all&keywords-type=airline&keywords-contain=3&keywords=Lufthansa&photo-year=2006&genre=all&search-type=Advanced&sort-order=0) has a photo of a CRJ-100 at Marseille taken on 15 July 2006, so it's likely this plane type visited multiple times

Comment: You guys can provide some precious infos ! Thanks :-)

Comment: A 737 is 2+2 in first class or business class.

Comment: @mins The cabin looks too wide for a 2+2 to me (for a size reference, look at the heads of the people seated in the frontmost rows and compare them to the width of the cabin), and the upper-right corner of the photo shows a three-seat passenger service unit (although the low image quality of the photo makes this less immediately-obvious than would otherwise have been the case).

Comment: @mins: I'd actually say it's probably a 3+3, since it looks to me like the overhead bins on both sides are the same width and since the PSU on the right is definitely a three-seat unit.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. From @Jordy comment and your observation, what are your conclusions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a 3+3: In addition to the details mentioned in the comments, there are three lights in the overhead.
And, in particular, it is an **Avro RJ85**. This matches the @Jordy research on the Lufthansa timetable and the details:

[image]

([right pic source](https://www.abcorporate-aviation.com/rent-private-jet/business-aircraft/airliners-charter/avro-rj85))

Comment: Nice sleuthing!